# compare elements of two strings java

Tags: java, string, split, contains

I want to check if one string contains a specific length of char-sequence in another string, f.e.

```
String user1_hobbies = "friends, cinema/outside"
String user2_hobbies = "outside, going out with friends"
boolean check;

if (user1_hobbies.contains(user2_hobbies)){
check = true;
} else
{check = false
}
```

ofc this attempt doesn't work because the whole string must contain the whole char-sequence. I just want to check, if only parts of both string will match... in this case it shall match because "friends" or "outside" are matching.

Comment: You can extract only the "words" from your first sentence and for each one of them, check if string2 contains that word

Comment: You're not using the right abstraction. Use a Set<String>, instead of a comma-separated String.

Comment: Since you didn't limit overlaps to words only, you should look at [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) for a better algorithm. Example: `"we were the best of friends"` vs `"we were the worst of friends"`, overlap would be `"st of friends"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the tip from @JBNizet, you could create two sets of words for the two sentences and then check to see if the intersection between the two sets be non-empty:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(user1_hobbies.split(" ")));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(user2_hobbies.split(" ")));
set1.retainAll(set2);

if (set1.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("There was a match.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("There were no matches.");
}
```

You might want to first remove any extraneous punctuation you might have, such as commas or slashes.  There could be even more work required in addition in your actual problem.

Comment: Probably want to split on `", "`, not `" "`.

Comment: This is a very liberal interpretation of the question. `"This was a house"`, `"Mouse is a small animal"` will find common word `"a"`, but *"one string contains a specific length of char-sequence in another string"* would indicate that we want some minimum length of common subsequence, not necessarily limited to whole words, and `"ouse"` is a [longer common char-sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: @Andreas These are valid points and the OP should consider them.  This answer is only intended to point him in the right direction.

Comment: If OP wants to check if sentences have a common word, then this answer is great, and it would seem so since OP accepted answer. However, the question is worded to say something very different, and the "right direction" is more likely a simple reference to the [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Anyway, this hint is more for other readers coming here. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend saving the hobbies of individual users as two sets of strings. Then you can easily find the intersection (i.e. common hobbies, set1.retainAll(set2))

or in your case set check=true if the intersection is non-empty!

Here an example from a previous post:
public class Test {

```
public static void main(String... args){

    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("hobby1", "hobby2", "hobby3"));
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("hobby4", "hobby1", "hobby5", "hobby6"));
    Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(set1);
    intersection = intersection.retainAll(set2);

    System.out.println(intersection);
}
```

Comment: There's no benefit to using a `List` here. A `Set` can compute intersections much faster. Your `intersection()` is O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks. It´s now implemented with sets.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert string to array with split function and then check like this...

```
String[] array_user1_hobbies = user1_hobbies.split(" ");
String[] array_user2_hobbies = user2_hobbies.split(" ");
ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array_user1_hobbies));
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array_user2_hobbies));
boolean matches = (a1.retainAll(a2).size()==0)?false:true;
```

hope this will help

Comment: You're mixing arrays and sets - arrays don't have a `retainAll()` method.

Comment: thnx dimo414 for suggestion that was my mistake, changing my answer